# apache camel - connect to remote server, ssh & check if file exists then scp/sftp

Tags: java, linux, apache, apache-camel

how to implement file watching and file pull or file download from remote server using apace-camel camel-ssh and camel-ftp ?

i want to connect to remote Linux server using camel-ssh and pool for a file until it is present then download it to local server

i am able to find lots of examples to sftp the file. but before sftp or ftp i want poller to check if files exist and check stability of file. is it available in camel ?

ta

Comment: 1. what do you mean by "check the stability of file" and 2. why don't you just try to transfer it and accept and handle the error you get if the file is _not_ present?

Comment: a file is created/written byte by byte. i don't to want transfer the file at the moment it appears in the drive, because for eg. assume at 6th mill second the files size can be 1024byte and at 60th second the file size can be 1024kb and at 60th minute it can be 1024M so i want to transfer the file when it is stable size (i.e) if the file is 1024M at 60th min and 1024M at 61st min and also at 62nd min i want to trigger the transfer so the file is copied perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a very unreliable way to test if a file has been written completely. What if the writing process pauses for some reason? Network latency? System load? Disk load? Apart from that: what you sketch is not even required: have a try yourself: if you read from a file on a unix like system (linux), say by copying it and the file is not yet written completely you do _not_ run into any such problems: the file is copied and the copy process stalls when the end of file is not reached until new data is available. In the end the whole file is copied the moment is is completed.

Comment: Oh, there is one single exception: if the file is not written in a single go, but some process _appends_ to is again and again. But in such case you never have a "stable file" anyway. You'd have to implement some other means of signaling, like an additional lock file or something.

Comment: i think this can help me.. http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/camel-users/201104.mbox/%3CBANLkTik3knXKeSUYw+rS-g1j7_tNNYHv4g@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Sure, you can do that. But why? Have you _tried_ what I suggested? It simply works!